# How to use \newenvironment and align in standalone document

Tags: align, environments, standalone

This works:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{f}{
    \csname align*\endcsname
}{
    \csname endalign*\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

\begin{f}
a = 1
\end{f}

\begin{f}
b = 2
\end{f}

\end{document}
```

But if I change `article` to `standalone` in the first line Latex complains:

> ! Missing \endgroup inserted.
>   < inserted text>
>   \endgroup
>   l.14 \end{f}

How can I fix that? My goal is to use `\documentclass[multi={f}]{standalone}` to get individual pages for each equation.

Comment: unless you specify varwidth standalone is like putting all the content in an `\mbox` so as in an mbox, you can put the align in a parbox to get a vertical context.

Comment: I guess `\newenvironment{f}{$\displaystyle\aligned}{\endaligned$}` will be closer to what you expect.

Comment: With `multi=someenv` you get a page for each appearance of the `someenv` environment; a single environment will not be split.

Comment: @campa yeah, that works :-) I maybe should have mentioned that I don't care about `\align` as long as I can do line breaks and align lines